# Pivot query replacing column name instead of adding a new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a dynamic pivot query I am using to retrieve data.  But instead of adding a new column to the query, it is replacing the last column.  Therefore causing data binding issues for one of my controls on the front end.

```
Set @SQL = 'WITH ResultTable AS (' + char(13)   

Set @SQL = @SQL + 'Select row_number() OVER (Order By CensusId) AS RowNum           ,QuoteId, CensusId, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, InputAge, Gender, SalaryAmount, SalaryTypeId, IsDeleted,bCensusCount, Vgtl, Vstd ' + @colnames + ' ' + char(13)   

 Set @SQL = @SQL + 'From (Select F.CensusId, ColumnName, ColumnValue, QuoteId, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, InputAge, Gender, SalaryAmount, SalaryTypeId, IsDeleted,bCensusCount, Vgtl, Vstd ' + char(13)   

 Set @SQL = @SQL + 'FROM #TblX F LEFT OUTER JOIN Census.tbl_Census c ON F.CensusId = c.CensusId) P ' + char(13)  

 Set @SQL = @SQL + 'Pivot (Max(ColumnValue) For ColumnName In ('  + @colnames + ')) as Pvt ' + char(13)  

 Set @SQL = @SQL + ') SELECT * FROM ResultTable ' + char(13)

 Set @SQL = @SQL + 'Where RowNum > ' + CAST(@FirstRec as varchar) + ' and RowNum < ' + CAST(@LastRec as varchar)   

 Exec (@SQL)
```

Vgtl and Vstd are the columns that I added.  Vgtl shows up fine, but Vtsd is replaced by different text.  I can't figure out what is causing the column name to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in very first line (select statement), when the variable `@colnames` is appended to the following line the very first column in the variable `@colnames` will become the alias for `Vstd`.

```
 '........, IsDeleted,bCensusCount, Vgtl, Vstd ' + @colnames + ' ' + char(13)
```

Therefor add another comma after the column `Vstd` and it should fix the issue something like....

```
 '........, IsDeleted,bCensusCount, Vgtl, Vstd, ' + @colnames + ' ' + char(13)
```

Comment: You're awesome!  Thank yo so much @M.Ali